# How can I reindex a time series data?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that is missing datetime rows in between. I have now 7486 rows and I need 8760 (the whole year of 2017, with 1h frequency).

I am trying the code from bellow, creating this data_range and trying to reindex the previous. What I get is the reindex but none of the values are being placed, just all of them replaced with NaN.

I know it should be something quite easy but I am stacked. Tryed several versions of reindexing but none of them is working.

```
     import pandas as pd
     df = pd.read_csv('1166.csv', parse_dates=['datetime'])
     type(df.datetime[0])
    df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], utc=True)

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime).dt.tz_localize(None)
df.head()
    1166    datetime
0   41.481  2016-12-31 23:00:00
1   42.213  2017-01-01 00:00:00
2   42.888  2017-01-01 01:00:00
3   42.201  2017-01-01 02:00:00
4   41.834  2017-01-01 03:00:00
idx = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01 00:00:00',end='2017-12-31 23:00:00', freq="H")
s = pd.Series(df['1166'], index=df['datetime'])
s.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(s.index)
import numpy as np
s = s.reindex(idx, fill_value=np.nan)
print(s)
2017-01-01 00:00:00   NaN
2017-01-01 01:00:00   NaN
2017-01-01 02:00:00   NaN
2017-01-01 03:00:00   NaN
2017-01-01 04:00:00   NaN
                       ..
2017-12-31 19:00:00   NaN
2017-12-31 20:00:00   NaN
2017-12-31 21:00:00   NaN
2017-12-31 22:00:00   NaN
2017-12-31 23:00:00   NaN
Freq: H, Name: 1166, Length: 8760, dtype: float64
```